# Are articles useless sometimes?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

In my native language there are no definite and indefinite articles, and for me this topic is difficult to understand, so I ask this question. For me it is interesting, how do you think, what role do the articles have in English? And also, are there situations when the use of the article does not make any sense at all (that is, the article does not convey any information, not a whit, no whit), but to say correctly it is necessary to use it? If this happens, how often, how many percent of the use of articles in your speech does not make sense AT ALL. Or English-speaking people can not use articles, in situations when they do not see the meaning of their use (but when all people use them) and society will perceive it normally? 
If suddenly someone will understand me wrong, I don't want to insult articles or your language, I want to understand the state of things. 
P. S. I hope I translated the question correctly :)

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be answered in an effectively objective way. I would say that articles provide more specificity to what is being discussed. Do we *need* them? No. If other languages don't have them, and they get along without them, then we don't *need* them either. (Which is not to say that if they suddenly "disappeared" current English-speaking people wouldn't have a problem. We are so used to them, that we use them unthinkingly.) Is English better for having them? I'd like to think so. (But I don't know if I could *prove* it definitively.)

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. Unfortunately, I think this question is both too broad and off-topic for this site. Every natural language has features that speakers of other languages might consider "useless." Russian doesn't have articles. English doesn't have grammatical gender. Mandarin Chinese doesn't inflect for tense. Korean doesn't inflect for number. It can be counterproductive for a learner to attempt to draw parallels between languages, especially the more distantly related ones.

Comment: The article almost always carries *some* information.  It's a question of opinion whether this could be obtained instead from the context without any articles -- probably so, but I'm sure some nuance would be lost.  I suggest you treat it like music.  Like any other language, English has a certain *rhythm* to it, and articles help you keep the beat.

Comment: I think the question might be made sufficiently narrow by asking "is there a grammatically correct English sentence containing an article, that would become non-grammatical if "the" was substituted with "a" (or the zero article as appropriate)

Comment: Of interest at EL&U: *[Is the word 'the' unnecessary in the English language?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/450771/)*

Comment: @JamesK You would have to be careful here of saying that something is ungrammatical if the article is removed. It can't be called that *just* because there is no article. If the point of the argument is that meaning can still be inferred without it, then the real question is, is there a sentence that cannot be understood *in any way at all* without an article? Even if it seems completely awkward, if some meaning can be ascribed to it, then it would not "prove* the necessity of an article . . .

Comment: meaning, grammar different two things are.   meaning ascribed can, but grammar none....  My point being that if a sentence requires a particular article in order for it to be grammatically well-formed then the choice of article carries no meaning.  For example in french La chien is not correct it must be Le chien. The choice la or le does not carry meaning

Comment: To narrow down the scope of your question, you might add some examples that illustrate your concern. What you wrote may be valid, but how to evaluate or respond?

Answer (score 1):

It's a common problem for English learners - not enough articles, or too many.

Here is a usage that does not require articles:

> crops are grown in fields

which is a general statement about where crops are grown. But

> crops are grown in the fields

is about what particular fields are used for (arable as opposed to grazing). Also there is

> the crops are grown in greenhouses

which says that particular crops are not grown in fields. Finally

> the crops are grown in the fields

has too many articles because it doesn't say anything that is not already known about **crops and fields** - ah! There it is again: no articles because it is a general statement.

Comment: "The crops" would imply some specific set of crops, though.  Without any further context I would assume this was previously defined, and read back to see if I missed anything.

Comment: Here's a good example to dissect: _He ate (a) lunch before he left for the airport_. That sentence can be written with or without the article before "lunch", and the meaning is essentially the same. Moreover, both versions are grammatical.

Comment: @J.R., the versions have slightly different implied meanings.  "He ate lunch" would generally be interpreted to mean that the specifics of the meal aren't important, but it was a "typical" lunch for him.  "He ate a lunch" would generally be interpreted to mean that he ate a meal that wasn't typical of his lunches, but it served the purpose of lunch in that instance, or that lunches were provided for a group of which he was a part, and he ate one of those.

Comment: @fixer1234 - I'm not sure I buy that distinction. If my wife told me, "I ate a lunch before I drove to the airport," I don't think I'd become suddenly filled with curiosity, wondering what food she ate. Nor would I think she added the article because her meal was different from her usual daily fare. That said, perhaps it's true that we're more likely to use the article in the cases you describe. However, even at the conference, I could say, "They gave us lunch at noon," or, "They gave us a lunch at noon." Surely you wouldn't tell a learner that the latter is right but the former is wrong?

Comment: @J.R., I agree they're both right.  :-)